# Formatting code after rewriting C# Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to make rewriter using CSharpSyntaxRewriter that change, whenever it appear,

```
YIELD(variable);
```

into

```
foreach (var item in variable)
{
  yield return item;
}
```

but it change

```
        public static string Upper(string s)
        {
            YIELD(variable);
        }
```

into this

```
    public static string Upper(string s)
        {
            foreach (var item in variable)
{
    yield return item;
}
        }
```

Here is some of my

```
if (@"YIELD".Equals(expression_name.Identifier.ValueText, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    var argumentName = (ArgumentSyntax)expression.Parent.ChildNodes().OfType<ArgumentListSyntax>().FirstOrDefault()?.ChildNodes().FirstOrDefault();

    var myExpression = SyntaxFactory.ForEachStatement(
        SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("var"),
        "item",
        argumentName.Expression,
        SyntaxFactory.Block(
                SyntaxFactory.YieldStatement(
                    SyntaxKind.YieldReturnStatement,
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("item")))
        ).NormalizeWhitespace().WithLeadingTrivia(leadingTrivia);

    node = node.ReplaceNode(
        expressionStatment,
        Enumerable.Repeat(myExpression.WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.EndOfLine(Environment.NewLine)), 1));
}
```

I've tried to add Leading Trivia to Block in myExpression, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your foreach statement is not indented is because you call NormalizeWhitespace in the wrong place. When you call it on a single note you will format said note without the context of the remaining syntax tree, so basically you're only formatting the following which you then paste into the existing code:

```
foreach (var item in variable)
{
    yield return item;
}
```

If you however execute .NormalizeWhitespace() on the root of the syntax tree (after you modified it of course) you format the entire tree which should result in the correct formatting.

Comment: Thank you. You'r right that is problem with NormalizeWhitespace. But when I execute on the modified root it doesn't change anything. I solve it by 
modifying myExpression in other way.